# Fixed point theory and the isGoodEnough function

Tags: scala, computer-science, fixed-point-iteration

In Coursera course `Functional Programming Principles in Scala`, the Lecturer talks about the `Fixed Point` and wrote some simple implementation of it.

```
def isCloseEnough(x: Double, y: Double) = 
    math.abs((x - y) / x) / x < tolerance

def fixedPoint(f: Double => Double)(guess: Double) = {

    def iterate(guess: Double): Double = {
        val next = f(guess)
        if (isCloseEnough(guess, next)) next
        else iterate(next)
    }
    iterate(guess)
}
```

Such implementation will allow the following function `f(x) = 1 + x` to have a Fixed Point.

However this should not never happen.
As in this function graph:

[image]

And this is what stated by Wikipedai:

> Not all functions have fixed points: for example, if f is a function
>   defined on the real numbers as f(x) = x + 1, then it has no fixed
>   points, since x is never equal to x + 1 for any real number.

The point here is in the `isCloseEnough` that I couldn't why it is written that way.

**I am here to understand the `isCloseEnough` and why it was implemented that way
That is All.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm isn't perfect, and it should obviously depend upon your choice of tolerance. If we examine `isCloseEnough`:

```
def isCloseEnough(x: Double, y: Double) = 
    math.abs((x - y) / x) / x < tolerance
```

It is really similar to:

```
| x - y | / x^2 < tolerance
```

Except that for some reason it is not taking the absolute value of the outer division of `x`, which completely breaks the algorithm when `x` is negative.

The idea though, is that we find a fixed point by finding an `x` that is *arbitrarily close* to `f(x)`, i.e. the difference between `x` and `f(x)` is as small as we want (below some tolerance). This works fine if we can find fixed points quickly:

```
scala> fixedPoint(math.sqrt)(2)
res2: Double = 1.0000846162726942
```

Here, the fixed point is `x = 1`, where `math.sqrt(1) = 1`. I used `tolerance = 0.0001`. Had I used something smaller, I would obviously gain a closer approximation of the fixed point `1`.

But now say I have:

```
def f(x: Double): Double = x + 1

scala> fixedPoint(f)(1)
res4: Double = 102.0
```

It finds a fixed point of approximately `102.0`. Obviously, this is wrong, but it happens because the difference between `x` and `f(x)` is *always* `1` for this function, and as `x` gets larger, `1 / x^2` gets smaller and smaller until it falls below the `tolerance`. If I make the `tolerance` smaller, I will find a larger fixed point.

```
val tolerance = 0.000000001

scala> fixedPoint(f)(1)
res5: Double = 31624.0
```

This is obviously also wrong. But the point is, for something to be a fixed point, I should be able to make `tolerance` *arbitrarily small*, and still get a consistent result. With this function, it is clear that for any fixed `tolerance`, eventually `1 / x^2` will be smaller than it.  *But*, for any `x`, I can always choose a small enough `tolerance` such that `1 / x^2` will always fall outside of it, so there are no fixed points.

This is hardly a mathematical proof, but the point is that the algorithm is flawed for some criteria.

Comment: I am out of the math field for a long time now, I am reading your answer and trying to understand it..